# DISTINCT - mysql query return same fields multiple time

Tags: mysql

I have a query where i did a join for getting two table information, All i need to do is unique the `tt_code`.

**My SQL**

```
SELECT cd.`tt_code`, ri.`complain_code`, ri.`repair_time`    
FROM `complain_details`cd
JOIN `repair_info` ri ON `cd`.`complain_code` =`ri`.`complain_code`
WHERE `cd`.`stat` = 'n' AND `ri`.`stat` = 'n'
AND (`cd`.`ass_to_per` = 'murad.hasan' OR `ri`.`ass_to_per` = 'murad.hasan')
```

**My current Output**

[image]

Desire output is unique `tt_code` rows, using SQL only. I know about `DISTINCT` but i am unable to achieve it.

Comment: DISTINCT works across all columns selected. So those are all unique rows. What you have to answer before we can help you is which row should be chosen for tt_code = 161559?

Comment: I got my answer, I use GROUP BY `complain_details.tt_code`, its done the job.

Comment: GROUP BY x will return arbitrary values for y and z. It's unlikely that this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT cd.`tt_code`, ri.`complain_code`, ri.`repair_time`    
FROM `complain_details`cd
JOIN `repair_info` ri ON `cd`.`complain_code` =`ri`.`complain_code`
WHERE `cd`.`stat` = 'n' AND `ri`.`stat` = 'n'
AND (`cd`.`ass_to_per` = 'murad.hasan' OR `ri`.`ass_to_per` = 'murad.hasan')
GROUP BY cd.`tt_code`;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already did this, i have a comment in my question.

Comment: @FrayneKonok Oh, Good For You. I didn't see your comment. (Y)

Comment: your use of GROUP BY would not be correct as you are not using any aggregate function (such as COUNT, AVG etc.) on the rows. It will return an arbitrary row for each group.